# SQL Server: error converting varchar to decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find sum from a column, and am getting an error

> Error converting varchar to decimal

I need to find the row which is causing this error.

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(columnName AS decimal(38,20)) 
FROM tableName
```

I tried using `ISNUMERIC`, didn't get any rows, and tried using `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%`, but that also didn't find any rows.

What is the way to find the rows which are causing this issue, as there are million of rows?

Comment: Did you check for null?

Comment: Try this one : sum(isnull(cast(columnName as decimal(38,20),0))

Comment: Don't store this data in a varchar column in the first place!

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following approach:

```
select *
from table
where 
  <column> is not null 
  and try_cast(<column> as decimal(38,20)) is null;
```

Comment: Perhaps `AND column IS NOT NULL` is prudent to add

Comment: Yes agree, I have edited, we don't know if the column is specified as nullable.

Comment: Column can have null values

Comment: Then hopefully the above answers your question? @Daksh

Comment: It didn't give any values back with the queries shared,